How can I mitigate odor after using paint scent?
I made a horrible mistake and decided to mix Lowe’s paint scent 1oz with a flat white ceiling paint. I applied one coat of it on top of a Kilz primer. The smell is unbearable and very strong. It’s been two days and I cannot stand being in the space.
What can I do? I’m thinking of renting an Ozone machine tomorrow morning and putting it in the space for a half a day. I also thought about putting another coat of standard ceiling paint, perhaps Sherwin Williams super paint with Air purifier technology.

Your first thought (the ozone generator) is likely the best approach other than ventilating the room very, very, very well. It would never even occur to me that anyone would want to add more scent to paint, honestly, and I certainly would not, but then I also avoid scented laundry products...

This is not an answer, but I think paint can spoil and have a foul odor.  The wife and I used paint that came with the house (about 5 years old) to touch up some problem spots.  We both got sick from the fumes.  We promptly threw it out and I do not recall the brand.

Have you ventilated? That's the first step to any such situation. You didn't even mention opening a window.

ventilation,  if you cant ventilate them maybe filter it,
